# How many times different letters appear in different words?

Tags: python

How to know how many times strings s , t and n appear in each of the following words to have an output like this:

- descriptions: s 2 , t 1 , n 1
- statements s 2 , t 3 , n 1

The words are not known in advance.The first thing came to my mind was to make a dictionary, but for dictionaries we can only have two unknowns, so any hints how to approach it? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Please mark your homework with the [homework] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
def counter(STRING):
  h=defaultdict(int)
  for i in STRING:
    if i in "stn":
       h[i]+=1
  return h
for s in ['description','statements']:
    k=counter(s)
    print k + " for " + s
```

Comment: But how to specify whether for example the counts s 2 , t 1 , n 1 belong to 'descriptions' or to 'statements'?

Comment: Thanks. The print should be like this: print k , " for " , s , otherwise would give the error: unsupported operand type(s) for +:

Answer (score 2):

In Python ≥2.7 and ≥3.1 [you could use `collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter("descriptions")
Counter({'i': 2, 's': 2, 'c': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 1, 'o': 1, 'n': 1, 'p': 1, 'r': 1, 't': 1})
```

(For Python ≥2.5 there is an implementation in http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/.)

The Counter class has the usual dictionary interface, so you could use `x['n']` to get the count.

```
>>> print("%s %s, %s %s, %s %s" % ('s', _['s'], 't', _['t'], 'n', _['n']))
s 2, t 1, n 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Naive implementation:

```
d = {}
for c in s:
  d[c] = s.count(c)
```

Comment: This would call `.count` too many times. Do you mean `d[c] += 1`?

Comment: @KennyTM: That would be part of a non-naive solution.

Comment: I guess `for c in set(s) & set("stn"):` would also be non-naive.